# Reduce rows read by the database engine for this aggregate query

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, execution-plan

I would like to tune this query - it is reading more rows than I would like.  I've added an index as suggested by the Database Tuning Advisor.

The query goes like this:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;

SELECT TOP 1000 project,
    Max(timestamp) timestamp
FROM   the_table
WHERE  deviceid = 581
GROUP  BY project
```

The IO , Time stats are like that:

```
Table 'the_table'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2373, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 390 ms,  elapsed time = 829 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

The execution plan can be found [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1lc076HF).

The dta_index this query seeks on consists of `projectnumber` and `timestamp`. The table has roughly 4,500,000 rows, consuming approximately 350MB and each `deviceid` has roughly the same amount of records (i.e. uniform distribution and each device has roughly 700K records).

My problem: even though I am requesting only the first 1,000 rows from the table, no matter what index I have created or how I have tried to re-write the query, I always ended up with reading +/- 700K rows (i.e. all the rows for the selected device in `WHERE` clause). I would be grateful if you could drop your tips about how to tune this query.

I don't think there is a way of narrowing this query faster than touching the approx 700K rows for particular `deviceid` with the first operator of exec. plan.

Here's a minimal reproducible example, including the table definition and insertion of two sample rows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[the_table]
(
    [primary_key_col] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Project] [int] NULL,
    [DeviceID] [int] NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [Quantity] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [primary_key_col] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[the_table] ON;
INSERT [dbo].[the_table] ([primary_key_col], [Project], [DeviceID], [TimeStamp], [Quantity]) VALUES (4825107, 1232, 587, CAST(N'2021-10-23T05:48:48.000' AS DateTime), 1);
INSERT [dbo].[the_table]  ([primary_key_col], [Project], [DeviceID], [TimeStamp], [Quantity])  VALUES (4825108, 6458, 581, CAST(N'2021-10-23T05:49:17.000' AS DateTime), 1);
```

| primary_key_col | Project | DeviceID | TimeStamp | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4825107 | 1232 | 587 | 2021-10-23 05:48:48.000 | 1 |
| 4825108 | 6458 | 581 | 2021-10-23 05:49:17.000 | 1 |

The indexes aren't part of the question deliberately, no matter which index did I try, I always have hit 700K rows for particular deviceID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"My problem: even though I am reading only first 1000 rows from the table"
You are not. You are reading the first 1000 results (without any ordering) of the grouped query - `top 1000` comes last in the processing order.

If you want to take a "random" 1000 rows that match the `deviceid` predicate then you could use a subquery:

```
select project, max(timestamp) timestamp
from (select top 1000
             project, timestamp
      from   the_table
      where  deviceid = 581
     ) sq
group by project
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but from my point of view you should re-think your query logic, because it gets all rows matching the `deviceid` and take top 1000 from that matching rows, not TOP 1000 from the table. You can see it also in your execution plan: on the right hand side is a table seek for `deviceid` and TOP is the last operator on the left side. That's why you get this amount of rows.